# Not able to download wifi driver because lwfinger/rtlwifi_new is not available teel me new repo and new steps

Tags: drivers, wireless, laptop, hp

I have hp laptop and I can't connect to my WIFI show always No Wi-Fi Adapter Found , to fix that I don't have the git repository , I have fixed that issue previously , but I re-install of the OS in later time ,

rtlwifi_new if this repository available with you please send me to get that, I can fix the issue

git clone -b extended https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git (currently not available )

Comment: What OS/release are you using?  (also if using a LTS release, the kernel maybe helpful too)

Comment: What wifi device do you have?

Comment: Have yo found a solution for this?